# IIS Default Website for Domains that have not been setup

Tags: iis, iis-6, website, defaults

Let me preface this with the fact that I know very little about IIS.

I have several websites on my server (Windows 2003 IIS)

I have domains that I haven't setup in IIS yet that point to my IPAddress.

When you try to go to these sites they redirect to the first site I setup in IIS.  How do I change the site that these unsetup domains go to? (It is not redirecting to "Default Web Site" nor is it redirecting to "sitebuilder(default)" whatever that is)

The server has Plesk on it, I use Plesk to setup new sites.

**I just want to figure out how to redirect domains that have not been setup in IIS to a page that says "Under Construction" or something.**

EDIT:

I have 6 websites setup in IIS. All the websites point to 74.X.X.X(I forget) and Default Website points to "All Unassigned"

I have AAA.com and BBB.com.

AAA.com is setup in IIS, when you go to it it pulls up what is in the vhosts/AAA.com/httpdocs/index.html.  So far so good.

BBB.com is not setup in IIS, but I own the domain.  When you visit BBB.com it takes you to vhosts/AAA.com/httpdocs/index.html and it remains BBB.com in the address bar of Firefox.

What else could it be?  Something about headers? (Sorry I'm a newbie)

Comment: @casoninabox: feel free to upvote away now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS binds to 0.0.0.0, port 80 by default. Assuming you've assigned the IP addresses to the IIS machine, the web site bound to "All Unassigned" IP addresses, port 80, with no host header specified will answer for all access to IP addresses on the machine that don't otherwise correspond to an IP / host header combination assigned to another site.

By default the "Default Web Site" will fit the bill for what you're looking for, but perhaps you've changed its configuration to be bound to some IP address / host header combination other than "All Unassigned" with no host header specified.

If you have a particular site you want to redirect incoming requests to, just change the settings on the "Home Directory" tab of the "Default Web Site" (or whatever site you set up on "All Unassigned" with no host header) to be a "Redirection to a URL" and specify the URL in the "Redirect to" text-box.

Comment: +1 Sniped again....  you punk ;)

Comment: I have a problem w/ doing that, don't I? (My wife is here saying "Honey, put that down so we can take a walk." and I'm saying "But wait! I have 10 more points today before I hit the rep cap!" Clearly I have a problem...)

Comment: Sounds good.  Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. See my edit for a better explanation.

Comment: I'd +1 you if I had 15 rep =P

Answer (score 2):

Since your issue is not multiple IPs going to a single "All Unassigned" pointed site, is AAA.com set to use a Host Header, or is it just bound to that IP?  If both AAA.com and BBB.com are pointing to a single IP for that server, and you aren't using host headers, then they'll point to the same site.

Comment: Aha.  AAA.com has a blank hostheader.

is that the problem?

Comment: I decided to update my server so I can't check it right now.  But I bet that is the issue.  None of my other sites have a blank header like that except for AAA.com and Default.  I deleted it from AAA.com.  Ill update when my server is back up.

Comment: I bet that's it too.  Without a host header, AAA.com becomes a catch-all for any site on that IP that doesn't match one of the other host headers.  Let us know:)

Comment: Server still down.  One of my updates killed it.  I'll post what happened tomorrow. =(